# grep output redirected to file produces binary file

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have a file `foo` with the content:

```
foo
```

Then I perform:

```
grep "foo" foo > bar
```

produces a `bar` "binary" (according to the file browser) file, with the content

```
[01;31m[Kfoo[m[K
```

If I try the same with `awk`

```
awk '{ print $1 }' foo > bar
```

produces a normal text file with the content

```
foo
```

I feel I'm missing something obvious here, is this normal? Why the discrepancy between the (at least) two commands.

Comment: I cannot reproduce with `echo foo > foo; grep "foo" foo > bar; file bar`

Comment: I should've follow the clue of the color pattern characters.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was simple. I had an alias of `grep` in my `bashrc` with the `--color=always` flag:

```
alias grep="grep --color=always"
```

The solution was just to unalias the command

```
unalias grep
```

and delete the alias from the `.bashrc`, then source it `. .bashrc`.